# Relationship between minimum eigenvalue of A times A transpose and maximum of the norm squared of rows

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times n}$ be a full row rank matrix where $N \leq n$.
Is the following true:
$$
\lambda_{min}(AA^{\top}) \leq N \max_{r=1,\dots,N}{\|(A_{r\bullet})^{\top}\|^2}
$$
where $A_{i\bullet}$ is the $i$-th row of $A$.

**My try:**

The right hand side can be lower bounded as the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \|(A_{i\bullet})^{\top}\|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \max_{r=1,\dots,N}{\|(A_{r\bullet})^{\top}\|^2}=N \max_{r=1,\dots,N}{\|(A_{r\bullet})^{\top}\|^2}.
$$

Also, the left hand side can be upper bounded as follows:
$$
\lambda_{min}(AA^{\top}) = \min_{\|x\|=1, x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\|AA^{\top}x\|^2
$$

I do not know how to go further to show it or disprove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have $x^T A A^T x \ge \lambda_\min (AA^T) \|x\|^2$, so choosing $x= e_r$ gives
$\|A_{r \bullet}\|^2  \ge \lambda_\min (AA^T)$.